# How to detect through C# code whether Crystal Reports Basic is installed or not

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, installed-applications

My C# .NET application uses Crystal Report which relies on the presence of Crystal Reports Basics for Visual Studio 2008. 
How can I programmatically determine, if it's installed or not. My target is to show the User a Message to Install Crystal Report if it's not installed already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it installs into the GAC (pretty sure it does, but it's worth checking), you can recursively check %windir%\assembly for the files that you are interested in. If they aren't there, throw the message.